# Add user to local administrators group on AD Joined Windows 10 device using AzureAD Powershell cmdlet

Tags: entra-id

One of our users needs local administrator rights on his Windows 10 AD Joined computer.
I was able to transfer ownership of the device to this user using the `Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner` cmdlet of the AzureAD powershell module. But apparently this does not give the user local administrator rights.

Is there a way to add this user to the local Administrators group of this computer ?

I have no physical access to the device and am not able to take control of it remotely.
I also do not have a Azure AD Premium subscription, so I can not use the web interface to manage devices and need a powershell solution.

Comment: Having AD Premium, I wouldn't run into your requirements, but look at this: https://www.vansurksum.com/2020/02/11/challenges-while-managing-administrative-privileges-on-your-azure-ad-joined-windows-10-devices/ under "Use another management..." the links might help.  The other method I would think would be to setup a remote sharing session with the user via joinme or something else and then using local command line options "net localgroup administrators /add "AzureAD\UserUpn""